# iPerf :WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries

Tags: networking, ethernet, c, testing, iperf

client side:

```
iperf -c 10.0.1.5 -u
Client connecting to 10.0.1.5, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 11215.21 us
UDP buffer size: 9.00 KByte (default)
[ 28] local 10.0.1.2 port 10055 connected with 10.0.1.5 port 5001
[ 28] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[ 28]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.25 MBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec
[ 28] Sent 893 datagrams
[/] #
```

In server side does not show anything.

I can ping from both sides.I am using iPerf version 2.0.13. It is software problem, how to recover it?

Comment: I have seen that same error before, but not now, using your same command. I am using version 2.0.5+dfsg1-2ubuntu0.1. Interesting, I get `UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)`

Answer (score 0):

This warning indicates the client didn't receive an acknowledgement from the server about the final packet or end of test.  The client indicates to the server that it wants to end the traffic test by sending a negative sequence no.  Either the server didn't receive those packets or its acknowledgement back to the client got dropped.  The output from the server would help diagnose.